# $useTable is not working

Tags: model, controller, connection

I am planning to use cake php as webservice.

I bulid the url like this

```
host/al_ecom_service/Category/getCategoryDetails/id/1/
```

Here I can get the output as a json (did some changes in while return).

It working perfectly in localhost.

Its not working after moved to the live, am getting following error

> Missing Database Table        Error: Table categories for model
>   Categories was not found in datasource default.

I assume that model $useTable is not working here.

```
class CategoryController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Categories'; 
var $uses = array('Categories', 'Products');
function getCategoryDetails() {
        $categories = $this->Categories->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Category.sub_category_status' => 1, 'Category.sub_category_id' => 1 ),
        'fields' => array('Category.sub_category_name,Category.sub_category_status, Category.sub_category_id, Category.main_category_id, Category.sub_category_status')
    ));
    echo json_encode($categories);
    exit;
  }     
}

class Categories extends AppModel {
    var $useTable = 'al_data_categories_subs';
}
```

Comment: The very obvious question is - have you setup your database in your "live" environment, and is it configured the same way as in localhost. I don't know much about this, but I'd guess it's unlikely to be the code shown that's the problem...

Comment: (And edit the question to add the error log)

Comment: My Error log
-------------------
2015-04-27 05:35:20 Error: [MissingTableException] Table categories for model Categories was not found in datasource default.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'table' => 'categories',
  'class' => 'Categories',
  'ds' => 'default',
)
Request URL: /al_ecom_service/Category/getCategoryDetails/id/1/

Comment: am done correct configuration in the live as well.

Comment: its not linking with my model files. by default its getting model file name from the controller name.